# NLP in Turkish with a DV that is a continuous number

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I know how to do NLP in R. Specifically, I know how to train a set of reviews on ratings and then predict ratings for a test set of reviews when the ratings are two-dimensional, i.e. 0 or 1. How can I do the same in Turkish and when my ratings are 5-dimensional, i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

Thanks for your helps